# What 1980s american sci-fi horror movie has a female cyborg villain with a flamethrower arm or breast as a weapon?

Tags: story-identification, horror

I want to know the title of this 1980s or 1990s american live-action movie in which the enemies or villains are cyborgs or humanoids. Its a very violent movie with lots of blood n gore.

One of the cyborg is a woman who has this fire blaster arm. The only other scene I remember is one where a guy is strapped to a chair and tortured by a mad scientist.

Comment: Is this live-action or animated?  Do you recall any particular scenes or character names?  Was the woman with the fire blaster arm a protagonist or an antagonist?

Comment: Agreed.  More details would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Its a live action movie. Im not sure if the woman cyborg is a protagonist or an antagonist. But i have a feeling that its a villain. All i can recall is that it uses fire as a weapon.

Comment: Actually her weapon is like a flamethrower. im not sure if its the arm or her breast. cant remember clearly. i only have 2 scenes in my head, this and a torture scene. a guy strapped in a chair tortured by a mad scientist.

Comment: NSFW (mostly) - http://l7world.com/2013/03/top-scenes-featuring-sex-as-a-weapon.html

Answer (score 4):

The movie with the female villain with flames coming out of her arm is called *[Class of 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_of_1999)*.

> Beginning narration states that throughout the 1990s, violence in American high schools had spiraled out of control, with areas in most major cities being taken over by youth gangs, resulting in some schools shutting down. Two major gangs vie for control.
>
> In 1999, special areas known as "free fire zones" have discouraged police from entering out of fear. Seattle's Kennedy High School is in the middle of a free fire zone, thus the Department of Education Defense (D.E.D.), a pilot special government agency, has been notified. Working with MegaTech head Dr. Bob Forrest, an experiment begins where three former military robots have become android educators. Forrest introduces school coach Mr. Bryles, History teacher Mr. Hardin, and Chemistry teacher Ms. Connors to the Board of Education. Impressed with the new teachers, new principal Miles Langford has announced that former delinquents who are imprisoned will be released as part of the new experiment, which would allow new methods of discipline from the new teachers.

....

> While they look for Christie and the teachers, they soon learn of the real deal with the teachers. Ms. Connors' arm becomes a flame thrower. Bryles' arm becomes a missile launcher.

### Trailer

Answer (score 3):

Or perhaps the 1992 cyberpunk thriller [Nemesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_%28film%29) starring Olivier Grunier?

Comment: Thanks but i already saw nemesis. Sadly it is not the movie im looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the movie called Alienator...
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096786/

There is that robot chick with arm blaster.
Don't remeber if it was a gore movie or not :/

Comment: Thanks but sadly that's not it. As far as i can remember, the villain uses flamethrower not laser blaster and has black hair.

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked about a sort of similar-sounding movie [here](http://www.badmovies.org/forum/index.php?topic=142541.0), which turned out to be something called [Mutant Hunt](http://www.1000misspenthours.com/reviews/reviewsh-m/mutanthunt.htm), could that be it? Trailer here:

Comment: I dont think i can tell if this is the movie im looking for based on that trailer  alone. I think im gonna have to see the whole movie first. Sadly like i said i only have a few scenes on my head about the movie. One is the female cyborg terminator-like chasing the good guys with her flamethrower arm or maybe breast and the other scene is very gruesome  torture scene. blood n gore. Anyways thanks for the response.

Comment: And i dont remember cyborg villains wearing sunglasses.

Comment: I just saw Mutant Hunt awhile ago. Sadly there is no female cyborg that has a flamethrower arm or breast as a weapon.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose if no one remembers you could always try looking at the titles/posters of all the various low-rated cyborg movies at http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&genres=sci_fi&keywords=cyborg&sort=user_rating,asc to see if any ring a bell, look for clips online of possible matches and so forth.

Comment: Also http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&genres=sci_fi&keywords=android&sort=user_rating,asc in case it might be a female android rather than a cyborg...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds almost like Terminator 3 ( female cyborg, energy weapon in arm, high body count, scenes could have been mis-remembered as torture), but I don't think you would be hazy on the details of something that grossed nearly half a billion in theatres.

Comment: Terminator 3 was released in 2003. OP is asking for a movie in the 80's-90's

Comment: Thanks for the response paul but like what i said its an 80s or early 90s movie.